# CloudDeploy[] on a complicated Manipulate[] object

Tags: manipulate, cloud-deploy

I have some complicated `Manipulate[]` object that I'd like to make interactively available online. The function `CloudDeploy[]` seems up for the task, but when I use it I get an online object that does not respond. The sliders and all work fine, but the thing inside just does not update.

The following example reproduces this behavior:

```
f[x_] := x^2
Manipulate[
 Plot[a f[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}],
 {a, 0, 1}]
```

I get the same behavior regardless of whether I do `CloudDeploy[]` on the `Manipulate[]` object only, or on the entire thing. My guess is that it does not work because it's not a single expression, so the solution would be to massage all my functions into the `Manipulate[]` expression, but that will be arduous to say the least, so I was wondering if there are better ways to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the [`SaveDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SaveDefinitions.html) option on ['Manipulate'](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SaveDefinitions.html) which you should save as a separate variable, i.e.:

```
m = Manipulate[
 Plot[a f[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}], 
 {a, 0, 1}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]

CloudDeploy[m, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

This will automatically store the definitions of any symbols used by the `Manipulate` into it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What a great tip, thanks! I only found that when I now put the `Manipulate[]` inside of a `CloudDeploy[]` the problem persists. However, when I save the `Manipulate[]` to a variable and do `CloudDeploy[]` on _that_ it all works out. I hope you don't mind me changing your answer to reflect that.